# Internet Access in Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I recently installed Ubuntu on a VirtualBox VM it installed just fine (much easier than on VirtualPC).  However I'm unable to get internet access from the guest OS (ie. Ubuntu).  Can anyone give me any pointers on how I might enable this?

The Host OS is Windows Vista and the hardware is an IBM Lenovo.

Comment: No solution listed under this question worked for me. I was about to go crazy before i got this idea of disabling/uninstalling anti-virus on my host machine. And, that worked.

Comment: Might be off topic, but I sure am glad it's here and Google knows it.

Comment: This might only help a small percent of the people, but: my problem was, I had VPN running on the host OS.

Comment: this is an old question but i would recommend to check to check the bridge connection status on your virtual box

Answer (score 35):

How did you configure networking when you created the guest? The easiest way is to set the network adapter to NAT, if you don't need to access the vm from another pc.

Comment: To add to ALassek's excellent answer, many wireless interfaces do not support promiscuous mode, and therefore cannot support bridged networking either (I'm not implying that you're in this situation, just mentioning it for the record). So yes, NAT is the first port of call in such cases.

Comment: Does this work if you change wifi networks http://superuser.com/questions/990021/change-wifi-virtualbox-internet-goes-down ?

Answer (score 28):

I could get away with the following solution (works with Ubuntu 14 guest VM on Windows 7 host or Ubuntu 9.10 Casper guest VM on host Windows XP x86):

1. Go to network connections -> Virtual Box Host-Only Network -> Select "Properties"
2. Check VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver
3. Come to VirtualBox Manager, choose the network adapter as Bridged Adapter and Name to the device in Step #1.
4. Restart the VM.

Comment: YOU ROCK!  But every one pls note on my VirtualBox Host-Only Network Properties, my setting was "VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver"

Comment: where the heck is `network connections` man?? I couldnt see it.

Comment: @prayagupd In Windows!

Comment: `Restart the VM.` -- It did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Yeah this answer really helped.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem.

Solved by sharing internet connection (on the hosting OS).

Network Connection Properties -> advanced -> Allow other users to connect...

Comment: where the heck is `Network Connection Properties` in windows?

Comment: Nvm, `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`

Answer (score 3):

it could be a problem with your specific network adapter. I have a Dell 15R and there are no working drivers for ubuntu or ubuntu server; I even tried compiling wireless drivers myself, but to no avail.

However, in virtualbox, I was able to get wireless working by using the default configuration. It automatically bridged my internal wireless adapter and hence used my native OS's wireless connection for wireless.

If you are trying to get a *separate* wireless connection from within ubuntu in virtualbox, then it would take more configuring. If so, let me know, if not, I will not bother typing up instructions to something you are not looking to do, as it is quite complicated in some instances.

p.s. you should be using Windows 7 if you have any technical inclination. Do you live under a rock? No offense intended.

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar issue in windows 7 + ubuntu 12.04 as guest. I resolved by

- open 'network and sharing center' in windows
- right click 'nw-bridge' -> 'properties'
- Select "virtual box host only network" for the option "select adapters you want to use to connect computers on your local network"
- go to virtual box.. select the network type as NAT.

Comment: There is a "'nw-bridge" option in windows?  Where?

Comment: Downvoted to bring the upvotes to an incorrect information down. So ppl don't waste time with this.

Comment: >>>right click 'nw-bridge' -> 'properties'

He forgot to add one step just before this step. We need to create network bridge. Follow below steps to create it.
 1. Open network and sharing center in windows. 2. select both "wifi" node and "virtual box host only network" noe and right click, we find create bridge network, choose it. 3. Network bridge node is created. 4. Right click this node, goto properties. Next steps are same. This solution is worked for me...!!!!